# SP - How to get of current site --> ParentWeb --> Child.title

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, web

I want programmatically to get of current site your Parent web --> Children(Url and Title).

```
                using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        oWeb.ParentWeb.......Childres.................
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You want all the subsites Title and URL?

Comment: Yes i need this for breadcrumb ::)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        foreach(SPWeb c in oWeb.ParentWeb.Webs)
        {
            //c.Title
            //c.Url
        }
    }
}
```